# How is it possible to use extern keyword before the function definition in C?

Tags: c, extern

As we know that extern keyword is used for declaring variables, functions in C..
like

> extern int a;

> extern int temp(int,int)

but what is the meaning of using the word extern in front of function definition in C?

like

```
extern int temp(int a,int b)
{
   printf("Hello");
}
```

we also know that extern keyword is associated with the declaration of variable ,not definition.
so how can extern keyword be used in front of  function definition as memory for the function is allocated when we define a function...
I hope , you got my question..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: why don't you just extern the declaration and leave the definition as it is?

Comment: `As we know that extern keyword is used for declaring variables, functions in C` And for defining. Here: [even on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern) there's `extern int i2 = 3;`. `what is the meaning of using the word extern in front of function definition in C?` Means symbol has external linkage, the same as for declaration. `we also know that extern keyword is associated with the declaration of variable ,not definition` Well, extern is associated with _symbol_ (as in has external linkage), and definition is also a declaration.

Comment: I can.    But actually i want to know the actual reason behind this question. 
because it is mentioned i in K&R book that extern keyword can be used before function definition.

Comment: And one important fact: symbols at file scope are `extern` "by default". Writing _at file scope_ like `int temp();` or `extern int temp();` and`int a = 1;` or `extern int a = 1;` is just the same. Here examples from standard draft: [C11 6.9.1p13](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p13)  and [C11 6.9.2p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p4).

Comment: but when i am using "extern int a=1;" in c programme , compiler is raising an error .
"'x' has both 'extern' and initializer"